# Blank Screen for Express-React app at Production: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < | index.html doesn't serve other files

Tags: reactjs, express, server, production-environment, create-react-app

My app works great in the dev environment, where I use proxies. After I pushed to heroku (production), I saw a blank screen. In Chrome Developer Tools, I saw the following two errors:

```
Unexpected token.         manifest.json:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     main.bac17543.js:1
```

When i click on these two errors, I saw that the manifest file, the main.css file, and the main.css file all have the HTML file as the source. It fails to load the other files from the client/build/index.html.

Okay, so experimenting with this, I found when I run "npm run dev," it works great on the client port. However, there's an error when the app starts on the server port and serves the index.html file with the following express code shown in the course:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    //Express will serve up production assets like main.js file
    app.use(express.static('/client/build'));
    //Express will serve up html file if it doesn't recognize the route
    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
    });
}
```

This code successfully serves up the html file. But all other files linked within fail.

After several reloads to Heroku, I reproduced the error by taking out the production if statement and navigating to localhost:5000 (sever port). After running "npm run build" from the client folder, I received the same errors when "npm run dev" is run. Even if i switch "build" to "public" to run index.html before "npm run build," I receive the same errors. To test if the html file was called, I wrote `<h3>testing html</h3>`, and the HTML successfully rendered to the screen as the only content. But it seems that manifest, favicon, css files, and javascript files were not found, returning the original index.html file and throwing an error at the beginning of the file: "<."

Here is my index.html file under the build folder:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico"><title>Compass</title><link href="./static/css/main.c092d6b6.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/main.bac17543.js"></script></body></html>
```

And here it is in the public folder:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <h3>this HTML is called, but the javascript file fails when served from Express</h3>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried both absolute and relative paths in the href and src attributes in both folders. Yet still no dice. I'm pretty confident the paths are right because they work otherwise, but for some reason it's not reading correctly. The build paths are server/build/index.html, sever/build/static/css/main.d3f5fbbb.css, and server/build/static/js/main.69f468ec.js.

Perhaps there is some configuration issue? I haven't touched configuration for webpack or anything. I'm just not sure why the buck stops with the HTML file when serving from express. Can you please advise?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same exact issue. I was able to solve the problem by setting my homepage in my react `package.json` from the github page that was auto filled to the heroku url since that was what was serving the static files.

Found this info to be helpful and led me to checking homepage property in my `package.json`

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/527

Hope this helps or someone else that is trying to deploy express and react from one repo to heroku.